# Components of Velocity in the Direction of a Vector $i-3j+2k$

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, classical-mechanics

I'm trying to solve this problem:

A particle moves along the curve
$$x=2t^2$$
$$y=t^2-4t$$
$$z=3t-5$$
where
$$t$$
is the time. Find the components of its velocity at $t=1$ in the direction
$$i-3j+2k$$
I started by solving for velocity:
$$V=\frac{dx}{dt}i+\frac{dy}{dt}j+\frac{dz}{dt}k$$
This gave me:
$$V=4ti+(2t-4)j+3k$$
At $t=1$, we have:
$$V=4i-2j+3k$$
Now the issue is how to find the components of this velocity in the direction of the vector:
$$i-3j+2k$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) onto that vector: $\frac{(4 i - 2 j + 3 k)\cdot (i - 3 j + 2 k)}{|i - 3 j + 2 k|}$

This is a scalar quantity, the length (norm) of the projection of the velocity onto $(i - 3 j + 2 k)$. If you want a vectorial quantity just multiply by the normalized vector $(i - 3 j + 2 k)/|i - 3 j + 2 k|$ again : 
$\frac{((4 i - 2 j + 3 k)\cdot (i - 3 j + 2 k))}{|i - 3 j + 2 k|} \frac{(i - 3 j + 2 k)}{|i - 3 j + 2 k|}$

Comment: This would result in a scalar quantity. I think they want the three components and not just a scalar quantity

Comment: Just multiply by the normalized vector $(i-3j+2k)/|i-3j+2k|$ again to get a vectorial quantity.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks.